# Freeware psd file editor

Tags: windows, adobe-photoshop, image-editing

Looking for a Windows freeware tool to edit psd (Photoshop) files. Should be able to both open and save psd files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hands down, [The GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/).

Answer (score 5):

If you use [Paint.NET](https://www.getpaint.net/) then there is [a plugin](http://www.psdplugin.com/) available that allows handling of PSD files (with [limitations](https://psdplugin.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Compatibility%20with%20Photoshop&referringTitle=Documentation)).

[image]